# Cordova FileTransfer exposing files to other applications

Tags: android, cordova, file-transfer

i'm trying de get downloaded files via cordova filetransfer to be accessible to other native applications such as the Download App on android.

i'm getting the files under /sdcard/Download directory but the problem is that when i open the Download application nothing is displayed ...

any ideas ???

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the "Download" application, you will only see files that are downloaded using the API DownloadManager. I guess that PhoneGap does not use that to download files.

But if it is visible or not (in Download Manager), all files in that folder will be accessible to other apps.

Or you can fork [my repo](https://gist.github.com/teusinkorg/6572976) for downloading and replace the download parts with the API of DownloadManager.